# @Transaction annotated method does not save data into a database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

In my unit tests I want to persist some entities and test their retrieval from the database. They were not being saved and I figured out that when the test method was also annotated with `@Transaction`, anything that happened inside it did not get persisted, even though the method finished without an error.

I had previously encountered a `LazyInitializationException` when messing with a many-to-many lazy-loaded association and annotating the method with `@Transaction` seemed to fix the issue, that's why I have been using it.

What could be the cause why the entities don't get saved? There is no reason for the transaction to be rolled back, since it does not fail.

**Code of related classes:**

```
@Test
@Transactional
public void plainPersistence() throws NullParameterException {
    User user = userHelper.createUser("User1", "password", null, null);

    Assert.assertNotNull(userDAO.findByUsername("User1"));
}
```

userHelper:

```
@Service
public class UserHelper {
    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDAO;


    public User createUser(...) throws NullParameterException {
        User newUser = new User(username, ...);

        userDAO.save(newUser);

        return newUser;
    }
```

UserDAO's `save()` method subsequently calls `save()` on `UserRepository`:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
    public User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're likely using [Spring test](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-tx), you should note that they are configured so that the default behaviour is to rollback the changes. To change this you should annotate your test classes with, if you are using Spring < 4.2

```
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = false)
```

otherwise, annotate the class with [`@Rollback(value = false)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/annotation/Rollback.html#value--)

Comment: Thanks, that does help. Though now I am getting an exception `org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly`, but it's a progress I suppose

Comment: yeps, this is due to a real exception going on in the logic itself. This you'll have to figure out